# Using 12.04, can I compile packages with gcc for 10.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc, g++

My development machine is running Precise, but some of my target servers are still running Lucid. I'm trying to set up my dev machine so that it can compile c/c++ for both Lucid and Precise. I already ran

```
aptitude install gcc-4.4 g++-4.4
```

on my dev machine but that unfortunately installed version 4.4.7 of the compilers where Lucid is running version 4.4.3.

After some googling, I found this:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/devel/gcc-4.4
```

which seems to be exactly what I want. Would adding this Lucid package to the Precise `source.list`  even work considering that this package was not meant for Precise? If so, exactly what url should I add to the source.list file in order to get it?

note: I'm not really looking to compile this from source if I don't have to. I'm not even sure if gcc/g++ 4.4.3 will even solve my problem.

I also acknowledge the possibility that I'm going about this all wrong. Is there a better or simpler way to compile for older versions of linux on Precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about GCC, your BIGGEST problem with the way you're going will be dependencies/libraries; the ones in Precise are usually much newer than Lucid.

The right way to build Lucid apps in Precise is to create a [Lucid chroot](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFgQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2Fcommunity%2FDebootstrapChroot%2F&ei=DuUWUNCuBMelrQG6vIBY&usg=AFQjCNGhgvaByYSZna4_Hqu3Xgdd-Bf1Cw&cad=rja) and build inside it.

Comment: I'm in the middle of setting up the chroot environment right now. Will I be able to run a gui ide (e.g. eclipse) or will I have to build via the command line?

Comment: Sure, you can run IDE or any GUI app -- please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot#Accessing_graphical_applications_inside_the_chroot

Answer (score 1):

No, it's risky and you can break your system, also if you want `gcc-4.4` just install it from the official repos in Precise.

Comment: The problem is that the Precise repo only has gcc-4.4.7, and it seems that I need 4.4.3.

Comment: in this case just download the source of gcc and compile the version that you need, after that you can use update-alternatives to use your newly created gcc gloabally or just make some references to it.

Comment: @LordofTime no, update-alternatives is designed just to avoid that.

Comment: I checked out gcc's source from the gnu site, but I'm a little weary on compiling it before I read up a little more on the build process. Being that 10.04 is still supported, I'm finding it surprising that it's so much of a hassle to build application's for it on 12.04.  I'd really rather find another option to do this without compiling gcc/g++ from source.